# php imagick throwing out "Uncaught ImagickException: unable to open file"

Tags: php, imagick

I am running PHP7.3.27 on Linux and running the line

```
$fn = '/var/www/vhosts/.........../myfile.png';
$im = new imagick($fn);
```

(where the myfile.png exists and can be viewed if run directly from the browser)
but I get the following error:

```
Uncaught ImagickException: unable to open file `/tmp/magick-5465d-r7LT2tZ8Ip': No such file or directory @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/604 in ....
```

When I run against another test file it works ok.
What is it about myfile.png that is causing this problem?